# Drag and Drop between Recycler view using ItemTouchHelper class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have got the other drag and drop between recycler views, but none with using ItemTouchHelper class. 
Is there a way to implement this ? 
It's to drag and drop items between two different recycler views.